# Executing Cygwin's "bash.exe" from different folder than "C:\cygwin64\bin" got dysfunctional BACKSPACE

Tags: cygwin

Observations:

- If I launch "bash.exe" from the folder "C:\cygwin64\bin" then the shell is open in a CMD.exe terminal and everything works fine.
- If I launch "bash.exe" from a different folder than "C:\cygwin64\bin" then the shell is open in a CMD.exe terminal but the BACKSPACE and other CTRL sequences are dysfunctional.

So my question is: How do I launch "bash.exe" from a different folder than "C:\cygwin64\bin" and keeping the BACKSPACE and other CTRL sequences to work correctly?

Attempts:

- I temporarily renamed the "C:\cygwin64\etc" folder to rule out configurations changes but other than the colors, the results are the same.
- I also copied the entire "C:\cygwin64\bin" folder somewhere else and "bash.exe" still got CTRL sequences messed up.

Comment: renaming `C:\cygwin64\etc` is an horrible idea. You cripple your Cygwin installation

Comment: I just wanted to see if it was a configuration dependency.

Comment: The same by copying the whole folder; I wanted to see if it was a DLL dependency,,,

Comment: Do you need to run bash from CMD or just open bash in a specific directory ? For the second use chere to install `Bash prompt here` in windows explorer

Comment: I just want to run bash.exe from a CMD terminal. I did try chere and I've got some access denied error.

Comment: I suggest anyway to run `bash --login` to properly configure bash and read all the startup files, specially the PATH

Comment: chere must be run as Administrator

Comment: I do have a "bash.bat" script that launches "bash.exe --login -i ..." and I have the same problem.

Comment: It sounds to me there's a hardcoded path in bash.exe... I might look at its source code.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I need to copy the following folder:

```
/usr/share/terminfo
```

Relative to where the "bash.exe" is located. So:

```
X/bin/bash.exe
X/usr/share/terminfo
```

Although it looks like a hardcoded path, I did look for terminfo in the bash source code and I couldn't find anything. So I'm not sure how to change the location of terminfo but that's another story.